Poles of general function $\frac{1}{1+z^n}$
I am investigating the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^n}dx$ for $n>1$ and am currently looking at the case when $n$ is rational. To do this, I am considering the slice contour with angle $2\pi/n$. My issue is the location of the poles of this function, where $z^n=-1$. When $n$ is natural, this is trivial, but I'm struggling to get valid solutions for $n\in \mathbb{Q}$. I have observed through plotting that the number of poles is the floor of n (+1 if floor n is odd), but would like to prove this and find the locations of the poles. How would I go about this?

It's best to substitute $y=x^n$. It will even work for irrational $n>1$.

When $n$ is rational so $n = \frac{q}{p}$ where $(q,p) = 1$ we have to use the definition of the complex multi-valued function $z^{p/q}$ hence
$$z^{p/q} = e^{\frac{p}{q}\log z }$$
why is multi-valued? Because $\log$ is! We have to choose a branch cut, let's say $\theta \in (0,2\pi)$ and $z = \rho e^{i\theta} $we have
$$\log z = \ln \rho + i \theta \\
z^{p/q} = e^{\frac{p}{q}\ln\rho}\cdot e^{i\frac{p\theta}{q}}$$
in our specific case
$$z^{p/q} = -1 = e^{i(2k+1)\pi}\iff \rho = 1, \theta = \frac{q}{p}(2k+1)\pi \quad k\in \Bbb Z  $$
how many available values of $\theta$ we have, it's easy to check that $k=0,\dots p-1$. Poles are located in this case on the unitary circle centered in the origin. This process holds also for real numbers and poles are no more finite.

I hope this helps!
